# Using JavaPOS with an EPSON printer

Tags: java, javapos

I'm trying to use JavaPOS and making a little program that allows me to print something on the EPSON TM-T200III but i don't quite know how to do that, here's what I've done so far:

```
    try {
        printer.open("POSPrinter");
        printer.claim(1000);
        printer.setDeviceEnabled(true);

        String textToPrint = "test";
        printer.printNormal(POSPrinterConst.PTR_S_RECEIPT, textToPrint);

        printer.setDeviceEnabled(false);
        printer.release();
        printer.close();
    } catch (JposException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and here's what i get

```
jpos/res/jpos.properties file not found
jpos/res/jpos.properties file not found
jpos/res/jpos.properties file not found
jpos.JposException: Service does not exist in loaded JCL registry
    at jpos.loader.simple.SimpleServiceManager.createConnection(SimpleServiceManager.java:179)
    at jpos.loader.JposServiceLoader.findService(JposServiceLoader.java:154)
    at jpos.BaseJposControl.open(BaseJposControl.java:493)
    at it.smi.retail.pos.JavaPOSConfig.main(JavaPOSConfig.java:12)
```

Comment: What was the result?

Comment: Isn't it TM-T20III(twenty) instead of TM-T200III(two hundred)? [Thermal line Printer](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=genre&pcat=3) And isn't there a sample program in the JavaPOS ADK? [EPSON JavaPOS ADK (for Windows OS)](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_soft&cid=7256&pcat=3&pid=6146), [EPSON JavaPOS ADK (for Linux OS)](https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_soft&cid=7290&pcat=3&pid=6146)